# How to monitor access to Firestore database by users on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to monitor access to the Firestore DB by users?

I'm wondering about this because, from my understanding, at least one user must be owner of a GCP project, therefore this means that a user has to have full access to the DB in the production environment.

Even if the project owner is a highly trusted person, I would like to be able to monitor reads of the DB by the user to ensure there is no unnecessary access.

I tried exploring Cloud Monitoring to do so, but was not able to find any solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can monitor a user's activity(data read, write etc..) on Firestore by data access audit logs.

Firestore's data access audit log is not enabled by default, So go to IAM&Admin -> Audit logs.

Then you can enable firestore audit logs like the screenshot below.

After that audit logs can be seen at Cloud logging.

Refer [this page](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/audit-logging#viewing_logs) to how can find audit logs on Cloud logging.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this totally answers my question!